# S0C7 while moving PIC 9(11) COMP-3 to PIC 9(11)

Tags: move, cobol, comp-3

I'm moving a field which is in PIC 9(11) COMP-3 coming from an INPUT file to PIC 9(11).
I'm getting S0C7 error or ABEND
Bellow is my code:

```
      10  FIELD-FROM PICTURE  9(11)  OCCURS       012     TIMES  COMPUTATIONAL-3. 
01 FIELD-TO        PICTURE 9(11).
```

Then:

```
       INITIALIZE  FIELD-TO                                           
       DISPLAY     'ST' FIELD-FROM (WS-CPT)                  
       MOVE        FIELD-FROM (WS-CPT) TO FIELD-TO
```

On "DISPLAY     'ST' FIELD-FROM (WS-CPT)", it shows numbers with spaces

> [image: Blockquote]

Finally, it shows an ABEND S0C7 on the instruction 'MOVE'

Comment: As the question is written, the answer is "yes".

Comment: The problem may be in the way you used to fill the table. Make sure you don't use REDEFINES in tables with COMP-x. Comp, Comp-x are for numeric calculations.

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes please mark the answer as "works for me", if not leave comments.

Answer (score 1):

You getting an abend because of invalid data.
Very likely a test of

```
   IF FIELD-FROM (WS-CPT) IS NOT NUMERIC DISPLAY 'BAD'.
```

will show bad data. Moving the data to this record, for example by `READ` or by a `MOVE` statement to the record you just place the data into it without any transformation or check.

When doing a numeric `MOVE` later (in this case from the numeric field in the table to a numeric field) and they don't have the exact same definition (USAGE, size) the original data is "unpacked" an then placed into the new field with padding/truncation as necessary.

During this unpacking you get an abend - because the data is not valid.

Solution: check if the definition in the record / table matches the input file, if it does "in general" then you possibly have a broken input.

As always: never trust input data, check it for validity if it is not performance-critical (keeping in mind that the `READ` takes more time than a common validation) and "external checked".

You could validate at least those numeric fields with a `NUMERIC` class check (but other data can commonly be checked, too).

Comment: I want to fill the file manually. What i should put on PIC 9(11) COMP-3 for exemple ?

Comment: You don't - you place `USAGE DISPLAY` data in for easy changes.... but that's a separate question placed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76182957/fill-file-field-pic-911-comp-3-with-data-manually (please accept this answer if it is working for the original question posted or comment on what is missing).